# Ubuntu and Windows drivers question?

Tags: wireless, drivers, keyboard, mouse

I'm probably the world's newest Ubuntu user; just installed it today. I'm so excited to start using it. However, I have a slight problem. I have a wirless keyboard and mouse called "Microsoft Wireless Mouse 3000". I had a driver for it installed on windows 7. But, when I went to the Microsoft Website to download the drivers, there were driver installations for Windows Vista, 7, and Mac OS X 10.4-7. There were no downloads for Ubuntu. :( What should I do?

Comment: is it not working or are you looking for feature of that software for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

- Wireless mice and keyboards that have a USB dongle don't need any drivers, in any OS - they will just work.

  If they did come bundled with drivers, the drivers will not usually be essential, but will only add extra features such as a little configuration console (that runs all the time in the tray, consuming resources), or activate extra features on the device, usually unrelated to the plain keyboard/mouse functionality.  Even the media/navigation buttons on the keyboard are likely to work without extra drivers these days.
- Linux tends to include drivers for as many devices as possible in its kernel (and related firmware packages).  As you have noticed, it is not typical for device manufacturers to include Linux drivers for download from their sites, so this is often combated by the fact the Linux kernel already has drivers for a lot of devices.